# Windows-XP embedded stucks on second hibernate

Tags: hibernate, windows-xp-embedded

I have the problem with the hibernate on Windows XP Embedded SP3: the second hibernation does not shut down the system (but stores the computer state). The scenario is as following:

When the system starts up after shut down or restart, it enters into the hibernation without any problem.

When trying to hibernate the system after it was resumed from hibernation it's stuck on "Preparing to hibernate" window. Then it's needed to press power button to shut the system down. After powering up the system, it resumes to the state before the hibernation.

Any help will be appreciated.